# "Спикер" - это кто? И нужен ли он нам вообще?

Tags: заимствования

В либеральных новостях было написано: "...предупредил на брифинге в четверг спикер Совета национальной безопасности и обороны Андрей Лысенко."
Этот Лысенко А. - он кто? - "Спикер". Если спикер Госдумы - это по-русски председатель, тогда Лысенко А. - это председатель Совета НБО? Или он официальный представитель, выступающий от лица СНБО? Потому что в СМИ пошла мода называть официальных представителей, выступающих, да и всех просто говорящих тоже "спикерами". Если иностранное слово вводит читателя в заблуждение и порождает вопросы, то тогда ЗАЧЕМ нам это иностранное слово? (Про современных журналистов я не спрашиваю - они не знают как на Руси и в России тысячи лет называли любого говорящего или выступающего человека, равно как и первое лицо в выборном органе.) А если "спикер" так необходим нынешним русским, чтобы заменить архаичные, с их точки зрения, слова "говорящий" и "выступающий", тогда, может, вместо устаревших, по этой логике, слов "говорить" и "выступать" ввести *поэтичное* и соответствующее их духу слово "спикать", а вместо дремуче-славянских слов "речь" и "выступление" блистать "спичами"? Давайте, русские (или расеяне), определяйтесь уже с языком, прекратите отрезать от живого организма по кусочку, хватит уродовать и издеваться над великим и могучим, переходите уже полностью на язык ваших духовных хозяев. Просто имитирование, подражание, копирование "белых людей" выглядит как позорное плебейское обезьянничание. И ни одна уважающая себя нация до этого не опустилась.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном конкретном случае имеет место простой перевод слова "рЕчник"(от "речь"), именно так принято в украинских СМИ с недавних пор официальных представителей каких либо организаций для связей с прессой. "Спикер" - в русском языке устоявшееся слово,означает того, кто ведет заседание, собрание. Переводить "спикер" словом "председатель" - ошибочно.

Comment: "Речник" - отличный вариант и для русского языка. Кстати, я заметил, что в украинском языке есть слова, которые можно было бы с успехом использовать и в русском вместо американизмов. А если провести исследовательскую работу, то и в других славянских языках можно найти немало приемлемых для русского языка славянских слов. Однако не могу согласиться с "ошибочностью": "Спикер" Госдумы или Совфеда имеет ОФИЦИАЛЬНОЕ название должности - "председатель", а слово "спикер" - это, по сути, журналистский жаргонизм. Так что это не перевод, а тупое замещение русского слова английским.

Comment: Согласен, насчет "тупого замещения". Но по поводу "примера" не могу согласиться. Все эти "автивки"(вместо "машина"), "гурты"(вместо "группа"),"видсотки"(вместо "проценты"), "геликоптЕр"(вместо привычного "вертольот",або "вертолит", "милициянт" вместо "милиционер" и многие другие примеры украинского новояза запускаются на ТВ и радио с единственной политической целью - еще более отдалить украинский язык от русского.

Comment: Совершенно с Вами согласен. Украинский язык и создавался И.Франко и Грушевским с целью его отдаления от церковнославянского и русского языков.Самый кульминационный пример - это "парасолька". От фр. "парасоль" - "зонтик от солнца".Но француз НИКОГДА не назовет "парасолью" зонтик от дождя!По-французски он - "параплюи". Но для галицийских интеллектуалов это было не ведомо и не важно. Однако я про другое: о принятии в русский язык из братских языков именно СЛАВЯНИЗМОВ (а не их иных заимствований) вместо современных американизмов. Из ваших примеров подходит только "гурт" и "подсотки" или "отсотки"

Comment: "Парасолька" - уже вторичное заимствование, из польского, как и многие сотни других польских слов. Там тоже особо не задумывались.

Answer (score 2):

Нужен  нам  "спикер"  или  не  нужен  покажет  время.  Язык  сам  определит,  что  лучше:  заимствованное  слово  или  созданное  по  своим  шаблонам  и  из  собственных  слов.  Сначала  был  аэроплан,  но  закрепился  самолёт.  Модные  веяния  тоже  из  жизни  не  выкинешь.  Мода  была  всегда,  но  она  проходит.  Не  надо  паниковать  по  поводу  засилия  "цизмов"  -  останется  только  нужное.  Это  нормальное  явление  любого  естественного  языка.

Answer (score 1):

Тут некоторый разнобой в терминологии. Спикером исторически принято называть выборное лицо, руоводителя определенных государственных структур. "Спикер парламента". 
Здесь же в относительно новом для русского языка значении спикером назван именно "постоянный докладчик", "глашатай на ставке", "пресс-офицер" Но одно, впрочем, другого не исключает.

Comment: Исторически (с 1377 г.)спикером именуется высшее должностное лицо Палаты Общин(House of Commons) Британского парламента.Говорить "спикер парламента" - не совсем правомочно,в англоязычных государствах спикер - это руководитель нижней палаты, высшим должностным лицом Палаты Лордов Британии является Лорд-Канцлер, назначаемый кабинетом.Руководителем парламента США(Конгресса) является вице-президент.Спикером именуется руководитель палаты представителей.В однопалатных парламентах руководителя также иногда называют спикером,но "исторически" это необосновано,просто устоявшийся журналистский термин.

Comment: @behemothus 1) Будьте добры, приведите пример "спикера" как "выборного лица", но кроме парламента. И где "исторически принято называть"?  Спасибо. 2) "Спикер" в значении "говорящий" - это не новое значение в русском языке, а навязываемый журналистами жаргонизм в русле вытеснения славянских слов из русского языка. В русском языке уже есть устоявшиеся термины, причем закрепленные в официальных документах: "представитель", "пресс-секретарь", "порт-пароль" и др. Дополнительный четвертый синоним не имеет никакой необходимости за исключением вышеуказанной цели.

Comment: Варяг, а что неправомочного-то в выражении "спикер парламента"?
Другого-то *спикера* в парламенте Великобритании нет, как вы верно сказали. И В США тоже. Тут скорее можно придраться к моему определению "руководителя".    
  
@Гусляр, Исторически принято - это я про русский язык, как Вы могли заметить.  
    
Спикер Совета Европы  
http://poslezavtra.com.ua/spiker-soveta-evropy-novyj-kpk-uluchshit-nado-ne-tolko-bukvu-zakona-no-i-praktiku-sudoproizvodstva/  
  
Спикер клуба  
https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=%22%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B0%22

Comment: "Спикер" - от англ. speak "говорить";
"Парламент" - от ит. parlare "говорить".
"Спикер парламента" - "говорун говорильни"!:D

Comment: @behemothus Как раз в русском языке никакой истории для слова "спикер" нет! Эта "история" (и приведенные Вами примеры) - исключительно история деградации российского журналистского цеха. И ей всего несколько месяцев от роду. Только журналисты насаждают "спикер" в этих значениях. Первое значение в русском языке ОФИЦИАЛЬНО, в ДОКУМЕНТАХ пишется и звучит как "председатель". Второе значение - это вообще лингвистическое уродство и его не должно быть в русском языке. Вернёмся к истории. Дума была и до революции, но только тогда "спикеров" в ней не было. Потому что тогда писали в СМИ РУССКИЕ люди.

Comment: @behemothus "а что неправомочного-то в выражении "спикер парламента"?Другого-то спикера в парламенте Великобритании нет, как вы верно сказали.И В США тоже." Вот этим Вы хорошо подтвердили, что Россия не только копирует англо-саксонские институты, но и русские копирует их лексику. Это весьма достойно для уважающей себя культуры. Кстати, почему тогда во французском парламенте нет слова "спикер"?Они ведь тоже заимствовали этот элемент демократии.Боюсь Вас разочаровать,но "спикера" нет и в немецком,даже румынском, шведском, КОНЕЧНО нет в арабском, китайском и почти во всех дальновосточных языках.

Comment: Простите, что внедряюсь в ваш разговор!
Кажется, как немецкое SCHPRECHEN ("говорить"), так и английское SPEAK ("говорить", где буквы ПР слились в одну англ.Р) родственны русскому СПРАШИВАТЬ, СПРОС, ПРОСИТЬ и т.п.
В старо-английском - SPRECAN - говорить. 

В известном смысле подобные англицизмы могут сослужить русскому словарю добрую службу.
Всё что надо нам сделать - возглавить процесс.

Почему-то я уверен, что большинство иностранных слов, так сказать, засоряющих наш язык, на самом деле не являются натурально иностранными, например - английскими или американскими.

Comment: Часто, при более пристальном их рассмотрении, они обнаруживают русские исторические (славянские) корни.

Comment: В отношении русских ГОВОРИТЬ, ГОВОРУН и т.д. в латинском имеется свой GARRULLUS - говорливый (переход V-U).
В английском AUGUR - предсказатель, прорицатель, пророк и нек. др.